# No module named 'pygame' error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I got this error while learning how to code android games in python:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I looked up this error online and found out that I needed the 64bit version of pygame, so I went to this website:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

I downloaded the 3.7 version of pygame in 64bit, I installed wheel with pip and when I try to pip install the 3.7 version of pygame this error comes up:
"pygame-1.9.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of Python 3.7? When you start your Python at the command line, what information does it display?

Answer (score 0):

My python version is python3.6, and I installed pygame through the command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Is ok:

[image]

Maybe you can first update your pip, and then install it by this command.

Comment: I did install pygame with pip first, but then I got the first error I mentioned in the very first part of the question

Comment: @altai you currently aren't showing us enough information to help you. Show us the version of Python you have installed, and the command that you used to install pygame. Did it run successfully? What was the output when you ran it?

Comment: Code: https://imgur.com/a/9QNcJYp
Error:     import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: @altai When you run Python what version information does it give you?

Comment: I have python 3.7

Comment: But what info does it display when you run it?

Comment: Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: You need to install 32 bit pygame as you have 32 bit python installed

Comment: I would suggest just running pip install pygame and not bothering with the wheel file as it should pull the correct version for your system. You may need to add the --no-cache option to force it not to use the local incorrect version.

Comment: your python is 32bit, but you download the wheel is amd64, So you can't install it..

Comment: How do I uninstall the pygame version I'm using now then?